# What's wrong with my Recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I need to use recursion to for a method I'm trying to implement. The problem is recursion here isn't working as I thought it would. Here's the code I have and I'll explain further below.

```
    public void printer(int level) { 
    System.out.println("A Car " + getId());
    for (int j=0; j< carTypes.size(); j++) {

        carTypes.get(j).printer( Index.get(j)+1);
        if (carTypes.get(j) instanceof Toyota) {
            level = 1;
        }
        else {
            level = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++){
                if (j == Index.size()-1) 
                    break;
                if (Index.get(i) == Index.get(j+1)) {
                    number++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Is recursion working right?");

    }//End of for loop
}
```

The problem I am having is I was hoping that everything after carTypes.get(j).printer( Index.get(j)+1); would be ignored and the method would be looped. I know if this happens, I will have to find another to deal with my for loop but for now, I just want the recursion working. I am not entirely sure if the information I have provided is enough so if you need more just ask I'll happily give more info.

Thanks

Comment: What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: I have a feeling that there are several tasks being confused into a single method; should you instead have a low-level method that knows how to print a single car and a high-level method that knows how to call the low-level method on many cars, one at a time?

Comment: I have basically just open the debugging perspective in Eclipse (I'm still pretty new to programming) and tried to see exactly what is going on but even that didn't give me anything concrete which is why I decided to post it on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recursion: Calling a method from itself.**

Now, `carTypes.get(j).printer( Index.get(j)+1);` this line calls printer method each time but on different object.

So, in fact you are not calling same `printer` method, and hence recursion is not happening.

**EDIT :**

> I know if this happens, I will have to find another to deal with my for loop but for now, I just want the recursion working.

Replace

```
carTypes.get(j).printer( Index.get(j)+1);
```

with

```
printer( Index.get(j)+1);
```

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. How would you suggest I make it work then?